# Json to database without overwriting previous data in database sqlalchemy

Tags: json, python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy

I am fairly new to sqlalchemy, however i have a json file which i am dumping to the database and i don't want to overwrite existing data in the database, i just want it to append to the database

below is my code that dumps data to the database

```
with open('questions.json') as f:
                    final_question_data=f.read()
                    jsondata=json.loads(final_question_data)
                for item in range(len(jsondata)): 
                    r = Question(id=int(jsondata[item]['id']), question=jsondata[item]['question'], option1=jsondata[item]['option1'],
                    option2=jsondata[item]['option2'], option3=jsondata[item]['option3'], option4=jsondata[item]['option4'],
                    correct_option=jsondata[item]['correct_option'], exam_id=jsondata[item]['exam_id'])
                    db.session.add(r)
                db.session.commit()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're experiencing might be because you're specifying an "id" in your Question object. Ids are usually used to determine which row is affected in your database - if an Object uses an id which is already in the db, it will overwrite that row.

You do not need to specify the id, it should auto-increment and "append" a new row at the end of your db - if your table is setup correctly.